# Jersey, REST and web.xml disables @ServerEndpoint websocket when run in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, rest, tomcat, jakarta-ee, jersey

I know this is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26339217/serverendpoint-and-web-xml), but this question has not been answered yet!

If a REST servlet ist loaded my ServerEndpoint is not loaded. If I rename web.xml the socket is working as expected. I run this application on tomcat9. This is my Endpoint:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/talk/{BenutzerID}/{Grad}/{Accesskey}")//, encoders = MessageEncoder.class, decoders = MessageDecoder.class)`
public class talk {

//static Set<Session> peers = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Session>());

public talk()
{
    System.out.println("Talk started! " + this.getClass().toString());
}

@OnOpen
public void onOpen(@PathParam("BenutzerID") Long BenutzerID,
        @PathParam("Grad") long Kontaktgrad,
        @PathParam("Accesskey") String Accesskey, 
        Session session) {
```

And this is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After cleaning Tomcat the websocket worked.

Comment: Also found out that the params may not contain slashes.